# Pandas dataframe to BQ fail with timestamp column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, google-bigquery

I encountered with the timestamp format.

I want to retrieve current timestamp with a function and use it into a pandas dataframe as below:

```
df['CURRENT_TS'] = pd.Timestamp.now()
```

After that, the DF will be converted to CSV on a GCS bucket.
Following this, the csv will be ingested to BQ using **load_table_from_uri** :

```
Error:load_table_from_uri() : POST https://bigquery.googleapis.com/bigquery/v2/...: Invalid value for mode: TIMESTAMP is not a valid value
'message': 'Invalid value for mode: TIMESTAMP is not a valid value', 'domain': 'global', 'reason': 'invalid'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you explored formatting the timestamp column of pandas?

```
df['CURRENT_TS'] = pd.Timestamp.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')
```

Just make sure that you specify the correct data format options, such as delimiters, header rows, and data types (sometimes the auto detection might fail).

Comment: i tried but unfortunately i have the same error

Comment: In fact you are right, my error was during the schema declaration i misread the error log.